# How much will an undried hardwood shrink in the axial direction?

Tags: hardwood, kiln

At the hardwood mill the man at desk said that the wood they cut (red and white oak, and poplar plus maple and others) is not kiln dried and can shrink as much as 6%.  That makes sense to me and of course I would not build furniture with it, but for my application some shrinkage is not an issue width-wise.

My question is whether that 6% value is accurate for the axial/long/grain direction.  Considering an 8' long piece of oak 2x4 or 1x4, which is 96", I find it hard to believe it would shrink just shy of 6 inches in length when kiln dried.  I could picture an inch maybe, but 6", not so much.  Is my assessment accurate on this?

Comment: depends on humidity, and ambient temperatures and the range of temperature. Woods do tend to move...

Answer (score 5):

Wood behaves **anisotropically** (differently in different directions.)

Common values for radial, tangential, and axial (aka longitudinal) [shrinkage in red oak](https://www.wood-database.com/red-oak/) are 4%, 8.6% and 0.1-0.2% (not even called out in the data, but provided at the [shrinkage information page](https://www.wood-database.com/wood-articles/dimensional-shrinkage/), generically for all wood.)

So, in the direction you care about, 0.1-0.2% so between 3/32 and 3/16 of an inch for a 96 inch board.

*If you are willing to dry it first (kiln drying is not required, it's just faster) you can certainly build furniture with air-dried wood. Or you can set up a simple lumber kiln, using plastic, sunlight, and fans and kiln-dry it yourself.*

Comment: Also note that wood continues to expand and contract over the years as humidity changes, and that wood motion varies from species to species. There are tables which can tell you what to expect, but that's a topic for the woodworking stack rather than home improvement.

Comment: TL;DR: When building things out of wood, nobody, but _nobody_ worries about expansion/contraction in the long-grain direction. While your new kitchen table _will_ get longer and shorter with the seasons, you'd need to borrow equipment from NASA to determine by how much.

Comment: If you start from dead green and manage consistent points of measure, a tape measure from an ordinary hardware store will see it - but very few people start from dead green, and those who do tend to build things where it won't matter anyway. So they don't worry about it. Once it's dry enough for normal woodwork, it is pretty hard to see any variation in that direction.